# Automated Context Switching Between Projects via SSH and Multiple Terminals

Tags: linux, vim, ssh, putty

I'm looking for some guidance on an approach to automate the process of quickly switching between projects.

Putty Windows (2 of them):

1. Vim with project.session open (multiple tabs)
2. IPython open to the working directory of the project

What I want to automate in its respective windows:

1. Save all files, save session, close vim, change working directory of vim to next project, open related project session.
2. Close ipython (as I often restart it during development and want a fresh instance), change directory to next project'ss location, open a new ipython

A magic solution would be a single command that would change the state of both putty windows. However, since I have no idea how that would be done my current approach would be:

1. Attempt to figure out how to bind all that Vim stuff to a key press or a custom vim script that is used like: :SwitchProj "projectName"
2. Write a bash script or find a bash command that will allow me to type as little as possible to perform the directory switch and open new ipython interpreter.

As I have very little experience on Linux and SSH I would be interested to know how other's have solved this problem or would approach it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the Linux [screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) command should satisfy you. Google gives you many tutorials, like [this one](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-use-screen-command-under-linux.html).

<sup>I sadly confess that I am not very familiar with `screen`. Learning it is in my todo list</sup>

If you use the [Gnu Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) editor, you can also open many shell buffers inside (and other interactive buffers, like `gdb` sessions, compilations, `grep` search) and edit many files. I do that very often.  You can use `emacs` thru a [tty](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php) interface, such as provided by `ssh`.

You could also use `ssh` with e.g. `-X` to also redirect X11 windowing. For you, that means that you'll need to run an [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) server on your local Windows machine.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I think I'm going to start with [Linux Journal's story on it from 2003](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6340)